# Python Search through list of tuples and return based on Index With multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples that is a table of reference:

```
 classes = [('400002', 'Class1'), ('400009', 'Class2'), ('400209', 'Class3')]
```

I also have a list of of tuples that are records:

```
records = [('Record 1','400002','Memo1'),('Record 2','400003','Memo2'), 
 ('Record 3','400009','Memo3'),('Record 4','L-REF-96-1','Memo4'),('Record 
 5','400002','Memo5')]
```

In order to import I have to assign a class and encode it:

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
ref = []
nom = []
memo = []
classr = []
for i in records:
   ref.append(i[0].encode(encoding))
   nom.append(i[1].encode(encoding))
   memo.append(i[2].encode(encoding))
```

now I need to assign a class based on index 2  if it exist, else if the str starts with L-REF then give it a general class, else give it a different general class

I was doing something like this but it didnt work it always defaulted to the "Else" part of my if statement:

```
    for c in classes:
       if i[1] == c[0]:
         newclass = c[1]
       elif i[1][5:] == "L-REF":
         newclass = 'general class1'
       else:
         newclass = 'general class2'
    classr.append(newclass.encode(encoding))
 newimportlist = list(zip(ref,nom,memo,classr))
```

Expected output:

```
[(b'Record 1',b'400002',b'Memo1',b'Class1'),(b'Record 
2',b'400003',b'Memo2',b'general class2'), (b'Record 
3',b'400009',b'Memo3',b'Class2'),(b'Record 4',b'L-REF-96- 
1',b'Memo4',b'general class 1'),(b'Record 
5',b'400002',b'Memo5',b'Class1')]
```

Comment: I think your issue is that `classr.append(…` should be indented. Otherwise I can’t immediately spot anything technically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `ref`, `nom` and `memo` can be constructed more easily by transposing your list `records`.

```
>>> ref, nom, memo = map(list, zip(*records))
>>> ref
>>> ['Record 1', 'Record 1', 'Record 3', 'Record 4', 'Record 5']
>>> nom
>>> ['400002', '400003', '400009', 'L-REF-96-1', '400002']
>>> memo
>>> ['Memo1', 'Memo1', 'Memo3', 'Memo4', 'Memo5']
```

Now construct a dictionary from `classes`.

```
>>> classes = [('400002', 'Class1'), ('400009', 'Class2'), ('400209', 'Class3')]
>>> classes_dict = dict(classes)
>>> classes_dict
>>> {'400002': 'Class1', '400009': 'Class2', '400209': 'Class3'}
```

`classr` (which I assume is the name for your expected output) can now be built as follows:

```
>>> classr = []
>>> 
>>> for rec, clsno, mem in records:
...:    clsname = classes_dict.get(clsno, 'general class2')
...:    if clsno[:5] == 'L-REF':
...:        clsname = 'general class1'
...:    classr.append((rec, clsno, mem, clsname))
>>>
>>> classr 
>>>
[('Record 1', '400002', 'Memo1', 'Class1'),
 ('Record 1', '400003', 'Memo1', 'general class2'),
 ('Record 3', '400009', 'Memo3', 'Class2'),
 ('Record 4', 'L-REF-96-1', 'Memo4', 'general class1'),
 ('Record 5', '400002', 'Memo5', 'Class1')]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, fairly new at python

Comment: @DannyCabrera no problem! I edited my post to use the modified `records` after you edited your question. Now the correct output is produced.

Comment: @DannyCabrera also, consider using [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for nice, self documenting records.